# How to create a ragdoll effect on a human?

Tags: editing, effects, video-editor, after-effects, special-effects

I make an action(combat) short-length film and I use After Effects and 3DS MAX to edit it.
I want to make a battle scene where the one guy hits another guy and the second one is thrown away like a ragdoll.Could anyone please give me some advices or guide how to do an effect like this?
The following video resembles a good example of the effect that i am trying to create.

The only way i found effective is to crop the "ragdoll" guy and manipulate it by using the puppet tool (from after effects)...Also blur would hide the fake effect...

Thank you! :)

P.S.:The following 2 links are samples of the film that I am making!Hope you enjoy it!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48212109/the_battle_final.flv

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48212109/the_battle_part6.flv

Comment: Yes, you'd have to make a fake solution to this if you're not able to do it in 3DS Max. If you are however, you can make a model of the "ragdoll" and animate it all.

Comment: @50ndr33
Thanks for your response!
Well,despite the fact that I am a beginner on 3DS Max i am looking for some tutorials based on ragdoll effect in 3DS Max.<br/>
Ok!Let's say that i create a ragdoll in 3DS Max..Can i put on them clothes or at least different colors on the torso and the legs in order to be identical to the real human?<br/>

P.S. Am I allowed to  post a link of a youtube video here?Its a good example to show you how i want the effect to be like..

Thank you! :)

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) how to post a link to a Youtube video.

Comment: @GeorgTsabou I watched a  40 hours long training series on Autodesk Maya a couple of years ago, and I know how to use it very simple, but I've never really used it more than the trial I got. Yes, you would make the "doll", and put on it the clothes you want. Autodesk 3D software is exceptionally good at making it look real. (IF you are good at it, at least.) Try to recreate the reality. I'm sorry that I can't help you more. I can only say, a 3D program will do the best job, if you can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

it's not super realistic but this tutorial uses the puppet tool in AE to simluate a ragdoll effect as the dude is crumpled over the hood.

http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/advanced_car_hit/

Comment: thanks for the link!Although I have already seen this tutorial by Andrew Kramer I find it very useful!! For now I am searching for a tutorial on ragdoll effect in 3DS MAX environment!But if you find anything else you can post it here! :)